# JavaFX event after application window becomes visible

Tags: macos, javafx, javafx-8

I need to execute some native code to interact with the macOS menu bar, ideally immediately after it got initialised. IMHO, a good time would be right after the JavaFX application window becomes visible.

From the documentation, I thought that `Window.onShown` should do exactly that:

> Called just after the Window is shown.

But that does not seem to be the case. When putting a breakpoint into the event handler for `Window.onShown`, the window is *not* yet visible. Unfortunately at this point, the macOS menu bar is not yet fully initialised, so all my changes to the menu bar would be overwritten later by JavaFX's default menu bar.

For now, I'm just using a delay of 1sec after the `WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN` is sent, but that does not seem to be a good solution. So does anyone have a better idea on how to reliably determine when the window is actually visible or all initialisations have finished?

Comment: When do you normally do the menu creation during the initialization phase of the application? With the current implementation of NSMenuFX I had to move that after the primaryStage.show() statement and use Platform.runLater() in order to avoid issues.

Comment: I'm actually trying to adapt NSMenuFX to Java 9+ wich requires some native bindings. I tried using the same approach for setting the menu bar, as you suggested, but the timing seems to bit a bit different.

Comment: Yes, the timing is tricky. I know because I did the original adaptation to Java 9+ of NSMenuFX :-)

Comment: Hopefully we’ll find a solution to make this more robust against timing issues

Answer (score 0):

If you put a breakpoint in the `onShown` method the problem might just be that the window was created but you are blocking the visualization because of the debugger.

If this is not the case you could try to create a new `Thread` that only checks for the visibility of the window using the [isShowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#isShowing--) method of the class `Window`.

This should be faster than just waiting for one second after the `onShown` method was called.

Comment: That might work. The only question is if `isShowing` will actually only be true _after_ the window has become visible.

Comment: I had a look at the JavaFX code and `Stage.show` calls `this.setShowing(true);` which means `isShowing` will be `true` _immediately_ after `show()` is called, so that might also be before the window is actually visible.

Comment: IF this works, you need to make sure to retrieve the `showing` property on the application thread. JavaFX is not threadsafe and therefore a background thread may create a copy of the memory containing the property value and continue accessing it's own copy only instead of the property that is updated on the application thread later.